WaveShare 1.44 inch lcd screen and Pico W
I have been in the computer engineering / software engineering / computer science for quite a bit.
I have a pico w and am trying to use the 1.44 lcd pico display.
Display is working fine, but I can not get WIFI to connect when using the display.  If I give the incorrect SSID / PASSWORD the connect attempt times out properly.
But when I give the correct information the pico wifi connect jams.
I have narrowed this down so that when I don’t include the LCD software and use a PICO that does not have the hardware plugged in, it works fine.
I need some help on this or I will have to return items since this is simply not a good solution.
I have seen on the net that some others are complaining about WaveShare items and WIFI, this is strange, etc. with no fixes that I can see for Pico W
Has anyone else seen this issue.
Tried using C and C++ compiles, same results
Tried with the LCD  WIFI jams with proper SSID and Password for blocking WIFI connect.
Tried without the LCD works as expected.

"Has anyone else seen this issue." is a tough sell at Stack Overflow because it's hard to get a good concrete solution. If there is only one path to failure, you can get a  complete answer. If there are several paths, things get murky. And if no one's seen this before, you're probably out of luck. May you have good fortune.

Have tried to get this working with multiple displays, multiple power supplies, multiple PICO Ws, etc.  SO far nothing stands out and there are some others that have reported this problem with WaveShare screens.  I guess will have to dig into the WaveShare code to try and nail this down.

Well just got the 2.8" touch screen from Wave share and it works fine.  There is a bit of difference in the linking, etc, but with different code tree from WaveShare for the 2.8" WIFI seems to be working fine.... So more info.
